# Computer network port address

Tags: operating-system

In a computer network, are the port address (at the transport layer) and the operating system process ID the same or different?

If they are different, how are they different?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: running program is called process(in operating system) and the application is also called process, the application is identified by port address(according to networks) so that in operating system each process as unique process id. By this port address and process id are same or both different?

Answer (score 0):

No they both are different. The port addresses are used to identify a particular service that is running on a machine. It's basically well known to both sender and receiver. And most importantly they are reserved. A port number is used by a packet to identify to which process it should be delivered. Whereas a process id is a random number that is assigned to a process by the operating system. 
If port number would have been randomly assigned then the communicating parties would not be able to communicate properly. As every node would choose a port number depending on its choice.
Simply speaking your port number is something that is used to identify a particular service on a computer globally. And the process id is used to identify a process uniquely on your computer.

Comment: Whosoever down voted this doesn't even have the decency to give a correct answer. At least, read my answer and tell me where did I go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Different! Port number for a particular process is fixed whereas, the process ID is assigned by the CPU when the program starts and it always changes whenever the process is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Port addresses are well known and fixed for example http uses 80 as port number.

whereas process id is created by the cpu when it is loaded in the main memory. they are completely different.